# configure apache to allow directory listing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

Hi installed wordpress as localhost on my machine.  I wanted to access it from another machine on my LAN.  I can access the page.  But non of the images or css is applying, Looking in firebug it's riddled with 404 errors to all the files it required.  the path specifies the IP and not Localhost and exist in their locations.

I am trying to set apache to allow file browsing via the website I have set HTTPD.CONF and .htaccess but cant get file browsing the site is located at c:\xampp\apache\htdocs

heres what I have in httpd.conf

```
 LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

 <Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">

  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted

</Directory>

<Directory "/wordpress">
     AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/index.php"
    ServerName wordpress
 </VirtualHost>
```

in .htaccess

```
 Options +Indexes
```

the error.log doesn't contain anything that stands out to me

Comment: Did you restart apache service after conf changes?

Comment: Hi, I have restarted many times :/

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the option `+Indexes` in the corresponding Directory:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/apache/htdocs">
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: That didn't work, changed the path to c:/xampp/htdocs didn't work neither did c:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress

Comment: No you don't. You can specify it in any `.htaccess` file.